# Execute Two query in the same script php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made one script which is suppose to update 2 different table at the same time. The problem is that only one table get updated and I cant get why?

Logic is:

The script should update the record of job.status and customer.status at the same time after I click on update button.

Only the table job get updated.

I tried to run only the second query and does not work.
I tried to run a query to another table on the same database but is not working.

Any suggestion?

here is my code:

```
     <?php
include("connection.php");

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]', priority='$_POST[priority]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
  $results = $link->query("UPDATE customer SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
             }    
$sql = "SELECT * from job";
if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
}
echo "
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
/* Get field information for all columns */
while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "  <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";  }
echo "
        </tr>  </thead> <tbody>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $job_id = $row['id'];

    echo "<form action='' method=post>";
    echo "<tr class='info'>

                 <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
                <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>
            <td>

           <select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
                <option value='new' ". ($row['status'] == 'new'? 'selected ': '') .">New</option>
                <option value='progress' ". ($row['status'] == 'progress'? 'selected ': '') .">Progress</option>
                <option  value='wait' ". ($row['status'] == 'wait'? 'selected ': '') .">Wait</option>
                <option value='done' ". ($row['status'] == 'done'? 'selected ': '') .">Done</option>
                <option value='close' ". ($row['status'] == 'close'? 'selected ': '') .">Close</option>
            </select>
            </td>        

          <td> 
             <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='update'>Update</button>
         </td>
          <td> 
                <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm get_info'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' name='job_id'  value= '[$job_id]'> Customer Info</a>              
             </form>                 
                </td>

           </tr>"; 
    echo "</form>";


}
echo "
    </tbody>

</table>";

?>
```

----UPDATE----

I notice that when i send this query is working.

```
$results = $link->query("UPDATE customer SET status='changethevalue' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
```

And when I send this one is working

```
 $results = $link->query("UPDATE customer SET status='changevalue'");
```

----UPDATE 2----

I rewrote the query like this and is apparently working. But I dont know why.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

  $results = $link->query("UPDATE customer SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");

  $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");

}
```

Comment: You should probably look into transactions or triggers, to make sure either both or none of these queries runs. While you're at it, google "SQL injection" as well.

Comment: Your code uses the same value for customer ID and job ID --- is that intended?

Comment: Thanks for the tips I update my question, could you please check?  also Could you be more specific when you say that I should look into the transactions or triggers?

Comment: Above the line 
`$results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");`
add the line
`die("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");`
Then, run it again and it will show you the exact query you're trying to run in plain text on the screen.  Copy/paste the query into MysqlAdmin and it should give you a clue as to what error you're experiencing.

Comment: thanks for the tips @ LStarky. Learn something new. I anyway solved the problem rewriting the query but I am not sure how. I ll get back if I will have the problem again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in the update queries but make sure you are using corect column names or try `echo` the 2nd query and run in php myadmin f.ex.

```
echo $query="customer SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'"
```

then

```
$results = $link->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

The queries should work. Maybe your table `customer` is actually `customers` or the columns `status` or `id` are either named differently or have the wrong data type.

I would carefully copy/paste the second query directly into PhpMyAdmin or directly into your database and see whether it gives you any errors. Maybe it's trying to assign a blank status but nulls are not accepted?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. Table name is the same, columns name are the same, and data type are the same. I cannot copy and paste the query into php my admin because there is a POST variable that changes and the PhPMyAdmin wont recognize that

Comment: Above the line 
`$results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");`
add the line
`die("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");`
Then, run it again and it will show you the exact query you're trying to run in plain text on the screen.  Copy/paste the query into MysqlAdmin and it should give you a clue as to what error you're experiencing.